# How to make work SoapHttpClientProtocol with namespace prefixes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, soap

I'm using in a relevant part of my application a legacy SOAP webservice that has been working fine till now. They have made some kind of update that has changed the previous format to:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <responseType xmlns:ns-980841924="http://serviceuri">
      <ns-980841924:arrayOfType soapenc:arrayType="ns-980841924:__sometype[7]">
        <item>
          <ns-980841924:field1>DATA</ns-980841924:field1>
          <ns-980841924:field2>DATA</ns-980841924:field2>
          <ns-980841924:field3/>
```

The difference lies in the new use of namespaces prefix, **ns-980841924**.

My webservice wrapper class has been generated with wsdl.exe (and I have tried with svcutil.exe with same result). All the code makes sense, except the namespace that wsdl.exe resolves, that is **http://serviceuri**. Doesn't seem to use the prefix in the code.

When I try to call the methods, I get NULL as result. The technical department which owns the webservice affirms that no change has been made. Maybe the new use of this namespace prefix has been caused by the update of some component, but I don't know.

I'd like to be able to specify the prefix. I've been trying to directly append the prefix to the namespace property of the return types. Something like

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "ns-980841924='http://serviceuri'")]
public partial class ArrayOfSomething : Array
{
}
```

Specially the line (you can see my try of inserting the prefix before the namespace):

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "ns-980841924='http://serviceuri'")]
```

which unfortunately, hasn't work. I've tried similar stackoverflow posts, without any luck.

Comment: any updates to this issue?

Comment: Sorry @FabianKöbel, in this case it was so easy to implement again the feature doing a normal request via HTTP that I removed the previous implementation with the proxy. I left this open because I really wanted to see if someone can clarify what is going on.

Comment: thanks for the response! Is there a way to serialize the xml from the generated classes by wsdl.exe? Or did you use your own implementation for generating the soap request body?